# Can I see the MAC adress of my router WAN port?

Tags: networking, router, mac-address

I have a TP-link Archer C7 router. It is managed by an external company (lets all that Company A), and I don't have admin access to it. I do have physical access, but do not want to make a factory reset (I could, but they I'd have to pay them to come and reconfigure, which  is a hassle, takes days, and costs a bit). My ISP (not Company A) would like to know the MAC adress of the router for use in some troubleshooting. How can I obtain the MAC adress?

I can not login to the router management portal since company A has the login to that.

I tried to connected my Windws machine via ethernet directly to the WAN interface on the router, hoping a ping, or some obscure tab in Device Manager would show "remote MAC" or something alike. Did not find anything useful.

Is there a plain windows-utility that can solve this for me?

Comment: Look at the router’s label.

Comment: TIL: the MAC next to the wifi credentials is not the WiFi AP MAC, but the WAN MAC. /facepalm

Comment: If there is an issue, then turf it across to Company A to look at. It should be their job and unless you have a silly contract with them, then it should not cost you anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the WAN interface is set up for some kind of auto-configuration, however (usually DHCP or PPPoE) in which case it will automatically send some packets to the "ISP". So if your computer is on the other end of the connection, all you need to do is *look at the packets you're receiving,* as the router will use its WAN MAC address to send them.

You can use Wireshark to monitor received packets; start a capture, connect the cable, wait for something to show up, select a packet and expand the "Ethernet II" header.

If the router's WAN interface had a static IP address, then yes, you could ping it and see the address in `arp` or similar.

There is also a possibility that the WAN interface will answer to pings to the `ff02::1` or `ff02::2` IPv6 multicast addresses. Look up your Ethernet interface index in `netsh int ipv6 show int`, then suffix the address with `%index` and try to `ping ff02::1%123`. The responses (if any) will show up in Wireshark, though they might not show up in the `ping` output directly.

> or some obscure tab in Device Manager would show "remote MAC" or something alike. Did not find anything useful.

An Ethernet-connected device will never show up in Device Manager because the router itself is not a Managed Device (peripheral) as far as the OS knows – it's a network device; you won't see it there just like you don't see other LAN PCs in Device Manager.

Comment: good explanation and extra information! thanks!